# Cannot call add items to ComboBox when called it from another class, the getter of ComboBox returns null

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, nullpointerexception, fxmlloader

Expanded from here: [Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.getItems()" because the return value of "Controller.getMyBox()" is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391471/cannot-invoke-javafx-scene-control-combobox-getitems-because-the-return-valu)

My unachieved goal: After the user picks a date from DatePicker, the date will then be forwarded into ComboBox as an option.

**Sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="259.0" prefWidth="351.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <center>
      <ComboBox fx:id="myBox" prefWidth="150.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <DatePicker fx:id="myDatePicker" onAction="#getDatePicked" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

**Controller.java**

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
//  private SearchableComboBox<String> myBox;
//
//  public SearchableComboBox<String> getMyBox() {
//      return myBox;
//  }
    private DatePicker myDatePicker;

    public DatePicker getMyDatePicker() {
        return myDatePicker;
    }

    private ComboBox<String> myBox;

    public ComboBox<String> getMyBox() {
        return myBox;
    }

    public void initialize() {
//      ObservableList<String> defaultTicker = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Something");
//      myBox.getItems().addAll(defaultTicker);
    }

    private LocalDate datePicked;

    public LocalDate getDatePickedAction(ActionEvent event) {
        return getDatePicked();
    }

    public LocalDate getDatePicked() {
        return datePicked;
    }

    public void setDatePicked(DatePicker myDatePicker) {
        this.datePicked = myDatePicker.getValue();
    }

}
```

**UserInterface.java**

```
public class UserInterface extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Controller controller = loader.getController();

            primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.show();

//          ObservableList<String> toAdd = FXCollections.observableArrayList("a", "b", "c");
//          controller.getMyBox().getItems().addAll(toAdd);

            controller.getMyDatePicker().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    controller.setDatePicked(controller.getMyDatePicker());
                    System.out.println(controller.getDatePicked());

                }
            });
            List<String> addStuff = new ArrayList<String>();
            addStuff.add(controller.getDatePicked().toString());
            controller.getMyBox().getItems().addAll(addStuff);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

From here on, there are two situations:

1. If in class Controller:

```
public void initialize() {
        ObservableList<String> defaultTicker = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Something");
        myBox.getItems().addAll(defaultTicker);
    }
```

**Error output**

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Eclipse_stuff/projects/BTL-OOP-20201/Test%20ComboBox/bin/Sample.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2677)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at UserInterface.start(UserInterface.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2673)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.getItems()" because "this.myBox" is null
    at Controller.initialize(Controller.java:31)
    ... 24 more
```

2. If left the code as written above. (initialize() is empty)

Along with the error output, the interface appears as normal and date can be picked.

When I tried to set ComBoBox to be called after a date is picked, the same output shows up.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.time.LocalDate.toString()" because the return value of "Controller.getDatePicked()" is null
    at UserInterface.start(UserInterface.java:36)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Well, thanks in advance, if anyone could help me.

Comment: don't repost a question, instead edit the previous to clarify the problem

Comment: just repeating my comment to the duplicate: the NPE on accessing myBox is caused by a missing fxml annotation on myBox, so it's not injected. And datePicked is null because you never instantiate it (maybe time to revisit java language basics and learn about default field values?)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so so much. And I'm sorry for the duplicated question. I am just worried that I should follow the minimal reproductible guideline, but when I made one, it didn't seem to be the same issue. 

I really should learn Java from basic again, thanks for the help.